# Why is Laravel & Pusher not working on localhost but works on production?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm making a little dating app where I use Pusher and Laravel. I use an event called `NewMessage` and listening on channel `msg.{userId}`. Listening works, however broadcasting events doesn't. It works on production though.

My code is as follows:

NewMessage.php

```
    public function __construct(Message $message, $toUserId, $conversation)
    {
        //
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->toUserId = $toUserId;
        $this->conversation = $conversation;
    }
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('msg.'.$this->toUserId);
    }
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'NewMessage';
    }
```

ConversationController.php

```
event(new NewMessage($message, $toUserId, $conversation));
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have SSL connection in production? :)

Comment: yes, its on heroku

Answer (score 3):

Check the .env file of your production application and set `BROADCAST_DRIVER=log` to `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`.

Answer (score 0):

in config/broadcasting.php i just set the `encrypted` to false and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It works on localhost, there's one small detail a lot of people miss in Laravel's documentation: "Broadcasting is done via queues so that performance is not affected".

All you need to do is run `php artisan queue:work` and it'll magically work